# Python import : No module named Foundation

Tags: python, macos, foundation, anaconda

Using anaconda, as you can see below. I am importing a module called: applescript--no issue there--except with that within this module it imports "Foundation" specifically: NSAppleScript, NSAppleEventDescriptor, NSURL.

I get:  `ImportError: No module named Foundation`

How do I:

1. verify I have Foundation installed and
2. correctly map the path for import?

platform: mac osx 10.9 with Xcode ver. 5+  installed.

```
import applescript
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py_applescript-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/applescript/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Foundation import NSAppleScript, NSAppleEventDescriptor, NSURL, \
ImportError: No module named Foundation
```

Comment: It looks like that module has a dependency. You'll just have to download the `Foundation` module, whatever that may be. There is probably more about any dependencies from where you downloaded the `applescript` module.

Comment: do you have PyObjC installed (`conda list` and `pip freeze`)?

Comment: Try using py-applescript wrapper - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-applescript/

Comment: thanks for the recommendation tips: issue was indeed PyObjC not installed: Along the way I discovered a great document I would like to share, which helped me understand the Python Eco-Sysytem: excellent read: http://mirnazim.org/writings/python-ecosystem-introduction/

Comment: @Kevin: it is a good read except for `sudo pip install` part that shouldn't be used on Linux unless you want to break your system (many system tools and user apps are written in Python and their installations are not sandboxed: are you willing to bet that the package version that you've installed is compatible with your current programs, their dependencies (that you might not even heard of) as well as all their future versions)? Leave it to your Linux distribution to make sure that all versions are compatible. It is less applicable to OSX and it is probably irrelevant for `conda` usage.